# Why does the "A" disappear?

Tags: php, oop

I'm going through some Zend PHP certification questions and am stuck on this one:

**What is the output of the following:**

```
<?php

class Magic{

    public $a = "A";
    protected $b = array("a" => "A", "b" => "B", "c" => "C");
    protected $c = array(1,2,3);

    public function __get($v){
        echo "$v,";
        return $this->b[$v];
    }

    public function __set($var, $val){
        echo "$var: $val,";
        $this->$var = $val;
    }

}

$m = new Magic();
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";
$m->c = "CC";
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c;
```

Answer: **b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,b,c,A,B,C**

I know that __get() and __set are called when trying to access/set inaccessible properties but can someone tell me what happens to the $m->a? I.e why does it disappear?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "disappear"?  The output contains "A".

Comment: Well its a `Magic` class... It won't just give away its magical secrets!  Try using the `AbraCadabra` framework ;)

Comment: he was expecting "a," to be printed by __get but __get isn't called since `$a` is public

Comment: Apologies for not explaining myself better. What I meant was I was expecting the "A" to be output first but it wasn't, and I was wondering why. However, I see that this has been grasped below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo $m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.",";
```

Note that the string is being concatenated, but that `__get` outputs the name of the key. The lower case letters are key names, the upper case letters are the values.

> b,c,A,B,C,c: CC,b,c,A,B,C

`a` is *accessed* normally, not through `__get`, `b` and `c` are accessed through `__get` and the *keys* are `echo`'d first, their value is then returned, concatenated into the string and output *after* the output of "b,c,".

So what this shows is that the `__get` method is triggered for `b` and `c` but not for `a`, then the values "A", "B" and "C" are output, then the value "CC" is set, then `b` and `c` are accessed through `__get` again, then "A", "B" and "C" are output again.

Comment: Nice answer. One question though: why does `var_dump` behave the same?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: Actually no, it's fine, my bad. Var_dump doesn't behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

all the variables in the line

```
$m->a.",".$m->b.",".$m->c.","
```

are first parsed, before it is echoed.

So the call to $m->b executes the __get magic method, which then  echos "$v,";, same with the call to $m->c.
Only after all the values is parsed (and the output from the __get method echoed), then the return values is echoed.